# f has at least one zero in C

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $\;\lim\limits_{z\to\infty} |f(z)| =\infty\;$ .Then $f$ has at least one zero in $\;\Bbb C\;$ . How to prove this ? I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: Hint: what can you say about $\frac{1}{f(z)}$?

Comment: Rob's hint is excellent. I think you meant $\;|z|\to\infty\;$ in your limit...

Comment: it is 0 as limit

Comment: Will you please describe it in details sir?

Comment: @DonAntonio what's the difference? If anything the change  should be $= + \infty$ instead of $= \infty$, but it's fine as is.

Comment: Do you know "Liouville's Theorem"?

Comment: Yes but trying to link with it

Comment: Here are the relevant facts about $\frac{1}{f(z)}$. (1) Either it's entire or $f(z)$ has a zero. (2) it's bounded (because, for all sufficiently large $z$, $|f(z)| > 1$, giving $f(z) \le 1$). Now what do you know about bounded entire functions?

Comment: Is it 1/z????or 1/f(z)???

Comment: $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ - spotted in time for me to fix the comment.

Comment: @quid The difference is the agreemnet , or lack of, in understanding with a complex variable what $\;z\to\infty\;$ means. If, for example, the real part is kept fixed, say equal to one, and the imaginary part tends to zero, is it ok to write $\;z\to\infty\;$ ? I think it is not, and thus $\;|z|\to\infty\;$ makes it cyrstal clear that *both variables* (i.e., the real and imaginary pats) tend to infinity. Now, **if it is agreed** that this is the meaning of $\;z\to\infty\;$ then there's no problem, indeed...

Comment: @DonAntonio the meaning of $z \to \infty$ is the same as that of $z \to z_0$ for any $z_0$ in  the topological space  "one-point compactifcation of the complex plane." This may not have been taught exactly like this but something equivalent to it ought to appear when Liouville etc is discussed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose f has no zero. Then $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is a well defined holomorphic function. Since $|f(z)| \to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$, we know that $ \frac{1}{|f(z)|} \to 0$. So lets say for all $|z| > R$ we have that $\frac{1}{|f(z)|} \leq 1$. Also, the closure of $B_R(0)$ is compact and therefore $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is bounded there as well. We now have an entire, bounded function. Hence it has to be constant by Liouvilles theorem. So your function is either constant or has a zero.

Comment: But it cannot be constant as lim is infinity.

Comment: @mathislove This started with "Suppose that $f$ has no zero".  Then it was shown that "$f$ has no zero" $\implies$ $f = 0$, or is constant.  We know that isn't possible (because of the infinite limit, as you mentioned), so it must be true that $f$ has at least one zero.  This is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: But I am getting ,1/f is constant and nothing else.how to get f=0 from that?

Comment: If it has no zero, 1/f is constant  and therefore f is constant and not the zero-function. There is no complex number s.t. 1/c=0. And if it is constant, it can not fulfil the limit condition. Its a proof by contradiction.